# Why data is coming as NaN Values ? - Ex using website's API (Python)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract some data (using python) from the website : https://www.seminovosmovida.com.br/busca?q=

Unfortunately, there are some data from the column **'marca'** of the **df_final** dataframe that comes as "NaN' (I've manually checked through the website database and there is no missing value, the data is there!).

Could you guys help me with that, please?

Here follows below the code:

```
import requests as rq
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib, ssl
import time 
import win32com.client as win32
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import urllib
import math

#Query

session = rq.Session()

headers = {
    'authority': 'be-seminovos.movidacloud.com.br',
    'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC8xNzIuMjAuMC40OjgwODFcL2F1dGhcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU2ODg1MDMxLCJleHAiOjE1NTY4ODg2MzEsIm5iZiI6MTU1Njg4NTAzMSwianRpIjoiaUdSV0JuVWVpcTMyNzNEcyIsInN1YiI6MSwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.WwHWiK0qUUGxyEMiI_owE5YoyykmW__fA1RaEAxqO0k',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://www.seminovosmovida.com.br',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'referer': 'https://www.seminovosmovida.com.br/busca?q=',
    'accept-language': 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
}

params = (
    ('terms', ''),
    ('applyURL', '/searchapi/v3/search?apikey=movidaseminovos&sortBy=ascPrice'),
)

#Number of pages and response 

response = session.get('https://be-seminovos.movidacloud.com.br/api/v1/chaordic/search/search', headers=headers, params=params)

df = pd.read_json(response.text,encoding = 'ansi', lines = True )

n_items = int(df['size'][0])
n_pages = math.ceil(n_items/20)

params_list = []
for pages in range(n_pages+1)[1:]:
    if pages == 1:
        params = (
            ('terms', ''),
            ('applyURL', '/searchapi/v3/search?apikey=movidaseminovos&sortBy=ascPrice'),
        )
    else:
        var = '/searchapi/v3/search?apikey=movidaseminovos&terms=&page='+ str(pages)
        params = (
            ('terms', ''),
            ('applyURL', var),
        )

    params_list.append(params) 

df_list = []

for pl in params_list:
    try:     
        response = session.get('https://be-seminovos.movidacloud.com.br/api/v1/chaordic/search/search',headers=headers, params = pl, verify = False)
        df = pd.read_json(response.text,encoding = 'ansi', lines = True )

        df = pd.DataFrame(list(df['products']))
        df = df.T
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(df[0]))

        #df = pd.DataFrame(list(df['details']))

        details = pd.DataFrame(list(df['details'])).loc[:,['ano','quilometragem','cidade','estado_uf','marca','modelo']]

        df = pd.concat([df['id'],df['price'],details], axis = 1, sort = False)
        df_list.append(df)
    except:
        pass 

df_final = pd.concat(df_list,axis=0,sort=False,ignore_index = True)

column_names = ['id','ano','price','quilometragem','cidade','estado_uf','marca','modelo']
df_final = df_final.reindex(columns=column_names)
df_final.columns = ['id','year','price','km','city','uf','brand','model']
today = date.today()
df_final['RunDate'] = today
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran this and it appears the problem is with the API, it does not always consistently have the field `marca` filled in.

For example in one run I did, the json that came back for the item with `'id': '536949'` had no `marca`, but I ran it again moments later and the json had `"marca": ["Renault"]`.

You may need to keep executing in a loop until the API gives you a blob with all of the data you need.